# SQL HIVE | Duplicate lines in Table

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have a table like this where the keys are [c_1, c_2, c_3], I want to non duplicates in my table.

Input :

```
C1    C2    C3   C4   C5
A1    D1    V1   X1   F3         
A2    D1    V1   X2   F2
A1    D1    V1   X1   F3        
A2    D1    V1   X2   F2        
A4    D1    V2   X1   F3         
A2    D1    V1   X1   F3
```

Output :

```
C1    C2    C3   C4   C5
A1    D1    V1   X1   F3         
A2    D1    V1   X2   F2               
A4    D1    V2   X1   F3
```

Regards,

Comment: ```select DISTINCT * from yourtable```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
insert overwrite table yourtable select distinct * from yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select the non duplicated data by

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table
```

then you can truncate the table and insert the above result to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4, t.c5
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by c1, c2, c3 order by c4, c5) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

You can remove `order by c4, c5` if you are not interested in the 1st row of that order.

Answer (score 0):

Does aggregation do what you want?

```
select c1, c2, c3, max(c4), max(c5)
from t
group by c1, c2, c3;
```

This does not guarantee that `c4` and `c5` come from the same row, but it does guarantee that the triple `c1`/`c2`/`c3` appears only once.